# Adding a dynamic image to my Crystal Report

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I am using the version of Crystal Reports that is bundled with Visual Studio 2008.  I'd like to pass in an image as a parameter, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.  Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with VS, but here is what I would do in CR XI Designer:

1. Insert a default image
2. Right-click on the default image to view its properties.
3. Go to the **Picture** tab.
4. There is a formula editor for **Graphic Location**.  Put the formula for your filepath & name there.

If the image can't be found, Crystal will show the default image instead.  If the images are of different sizes, you'll want to play with the **Can Grow** and **Lock position and size** properties.